# javascript confirm() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the code that is not working... It just deletes the form without first prompting.

```
$(".delete").click(function () {
    if(confirm('You honestly want to delete that student?')){
        return deleteForm(this, "form");
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

See it all here: http://jsfiddle.net/broinjc/wR256/

Comment: your example doesn't do anything for me. clicking the [x] does not work either way - can you reduce it to just the code you think has the problem? I suspect that part actually works just fine and reduction is going to tell you where the problem is.

Comment: it's his other code... the first thing I tried was clean that JSFiddle, stripped everything that wasn't the del-button, and it worked... so @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, reducing it to the code that has the problem would basically tell him the problem, and that was something he coulnd't figure out...

Comment: You're duplicating IDs which is a no-no.

Comment: Your function is not executing. YOu bind the .delete event before you append the delete button. YOu should first append the button code and then bind an event to it
http://jsfiddle.net/wR256/4/

Answer (score 1):

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F3LZZ/)

*For those that haven't noticed, the first form can not be deleted (as intended), be sure to create a new form if you want to test the delete action.*

You have two click handlers for the delete button. The first looks like this:

```
$(row).find(".delete").click(function () {
    return deleteForm(this, prefix);
});
```

Change that to:

```
$(row).find(".delete").click(function () {
  if(confirm('You honestly want to delete that student?')){
    return deleteForm(this, "form");
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

Then remove the second click handler (the one shown in the question)

Comment: I'm very curious about this as I did the exact same thing and it still didn't work.  Your fiddle doesn't work for me either.

Comment: I'm not just posting words for the hell of it :p  It doesn't work for me, using Chrome.

Comment: Do you realise the first form can not be deleted (as intended)? Are you creating a new form before you try to delete?

Comment: No problem, I guess someone else did the same, explaining the downvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$(".delete").on('click', function () {
    if(confirm('You honestly want to delete that student?')){
        deleteForm(this, "form");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem because you've created one more element a (class="delete") at the same position with the currently element a.

Just remove this line and your code work fine:

```
$('.item fieldset').append('<a id="del" class="delete button alert tiny" href="#" style="position: absolute; top: 8px; right:0;">X</a>');
```

[image]